# NHibernate: Global caching across multiple instances

Tags: c#, caching, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, redis

Suppose I am running two instances of the same data service using NHibernate.
I understand NHibernate caching levels i.e First Level = Session, Second Level = SessionFactory.

Is it possible for both of these instances to run against the same Redis cache within the same caching 'scope'?
It seems to me this would be highly beneficial but perhaps I am missing something as it doesn't seem to be supported.

Is this kind of global caching possible with other technologies?
Is it undesirable for some reason I have overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

There is an nhibernate cache provider against redis
https://github.com/TheCloudlessSky/NHibernate.Caches.Redis

Comment: I have this provider but my question is more specifically can this architecture support sharing the cache among many instances of the application for example in a web farm?